# Calculate total size of a page map table

Tags: memory

I have been given the format for page table entries:

- Bit 23: Valid Bit
- Bit 22: Modify Bit
- Bits 22-18: LRU Bits
- Bits 17-0: Frame Number

Im told that the system uses 32-bit virtual addresses and pages that are 8192 bytes in size.

- What would be the total size in bytes of the page map table?
- If an inverted page map table is used what would be its total size in bytes if the LRU field within each PTE is reduced to 3 bits?

I have been helped with this problem, and calculated that the maximum physical memory of the system is 2GB. I'm not sure if I need to take the 32 bit virtual address data given into consideration when calculating the total size of the page map table.

Comment: I think the formula for calculating the page table size is (virtual address space/pagesize) * page table entry size. Given that, I would say that ((2^32)/8192)*page table entry size will give me the page map table size. Can anyone comment? I'm not sure what the page table entry size is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there isn't enough information to answer this question.

See, the page table size is equal to the number of entries in it times the size of each entry.

First, I don't know if the page table entries are 24-bit-long or 32-bit-long or bigger. That's not explicitly specified.

Second, if there's only one page table involved in translation of virtual addresses into physical addresses, a page table has to cover the entire 32 bits of the virtual address. Since a single PTE only handles 13 (because the page size is 2^13=8192 bytes), you'd need 2^(32-13)=2^19 entries in this case.

Now, if there's a hierarchy of page tables involved in the translation, in other words, the entries of the first page table (often called page directory) point to a second-level page table and those either point to the code/data pages or to a third-level page table and so on, you get the idea... in this case the answer is going to be different. But it's not specified whether there's just one page table or a chain of multiple page tables.

In my opinion, a page table of 2^19 entries is unlikely. A page table is usually the size of a single page (sometimes smaller). So, if, for example, PTEs are 32-bit, you have 8192/4=2048 PTEs in a PT and that covers only 11 (2^11=2048) out of the remaining 32-13=19 bits of the virtual address. The other 19-11=8 bits of the virtual address must be taken care of by another page table, page directory, having only 2^8=256 entries, provided the entries are the same in the page table and page directory.

Given the provided information, there's no definitive answer here, only guesses.

Comment: Hey Thanks! I worked with another person, and I think the page table entries are 24 bits, since the format of the page table entries is given. The frame/page number covers 18 bits, lru covers 5 bits, modify bit is 1 bit, and valid bit is 1, which equals 24. Does that help? You seem to be good at this subject. Does that information help out?

Comment: As I said, page tables are usually the size of a page and contain a power of two entries. It would look very odd to me to have 3-byte entries (not a power of two size, not even an even size) in a 8192-byte-long page table - it would have 2730 entries and 2 unused bytes. No sane engineer/architect would design such a page table. It's inconvenient to work with.

Comment: What do you mean 3 byte entries? Are you talking about the LRU bits? I agree with you, this is just a HW problem, so I'm guessing the professor just made something up. If you can guide me through this one, I would surely appreciate it, based on the data given.

Comment: 24 bits = 3 bytes (assuming a byte is 8-bit).

Comment: ahh I see. So based on the fact that the page table entries are 24 bits, could you help me solve it? I thought he would have given us everything we need. I'm not even sure how the 32 bit virtual address piece is helpful here. I think you helped me solve for the 2GB max physical memory piece of this problem.

Comment: See your textbook or Wikipedia on how [virtual to physical address translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table) works. That should help you understand how the virtual address size is involved. See the diagrams and text. One thing that bothers me a little is the fact that this is done with an inverted page table, so the logic might be somewhat different (I'm not very familiar with these).

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your math, but 3*(2^18)=786432 or 768KB (1KB = 1024 bytes).

Comment: Does it seem reasonable for a page map table to be that size? I think based on the information given, that's what I'm going to go with (768Kb).